New version of Windows 10 on separate hard drive
I cannot connect or open programs and apps, that are still on the "secondary" hard drive, that had worked using Windows 10.

What programs? What permissions do you have to the files on this secondary drive? What error message(s) do you get? What have you tried so far?

A lot of applications will not work just because you have the files on the harddisk. if the app created or edited registry entries during install, or added shared dlls to system32 or registered services or a bunch of other things will have to be reinstalled on the new system. you can't just run it from the files left over from the old system.

Can you please [edit] and more explicitly state what your question is exactly?
